# Javascript: Get UTC Date Object by UTC Offset

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

we're having lots of location-based data and one parameter for each location/city is a `timezone` parameter, which holds the UTC offset for that local timezone.

For example: 
`vienna: 1`
`denver: -7`

Now, I want to get the local time for those cities.

Up until now I was using this:

`var date = new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000);`

But today, I realized the hours are +1 off.

How can I get local times by UTC offset in Javascript?

Comment: Why are you creating date objects for arbitrary timestamps? You should use the timezone offsets only for formatting and parsing.

Comment: What do you mean arbitrary timestamps? I want the local time for a specific location by only knowing the UTC offset. What I use it for is totally irrelevant. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: That `date` you are constructing is in the future (for positive offsets) or past (for negative ones), but I guess you want to get the current time? JS `Date` objects are absolut, they don't have an offset. I suppose you want to display the (current) time as a string in some specific timezone? Then please show us the code you use to create that string.

Comment: @Bergi. If I am in Germany and I launch a Google Map on Denver, and I want to display the local time in Denver, than that time - compared to me - is in the past. While Japan is in the future. I do not only want to display that date, but also use it for some other "localized" calculations. I just want the local time for a specific location - no matter where the user is.

Comment: I think my calculation that I posted is correct. It's the summer-winter time that is making it 1 hour off.

Comment: No, please don't do "localized calculations". Treat `Date` objects always and only as UTC timestamps. The time in Denver is no different than the time here (ignoring relativistic effects). You can still display it using "Denver time format" anywhere, but that's only a formatting option.

Comment: @Bergi I see where you're coming from. We have localized data, like a string that should be "SomethingA" when it's 11am in Denver. At 12am it should be "SomethingB" - and so forth. It's data, depending on the local time of a city. To get that data from any client, we need to find the time for that city. Again: I think my calculations are correct - but it doesn't pay attention to summer-time yet.

Comment: Hm,  `date.getUTCHours() + offsetTable[city]` should always give the correct local time, regardless of summer time or not.

Answer (score -3):

use this:

```
 var d = new Date()
 var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: that's not what I'm asking for.